# Is there any framework which can switch views in wpf in mvvm pattern (No code-behind at all)

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am creating a library application with mvvm pattern. I have bookview, studentview, issueBookview and each view has its own viewmodel. On each view, there is button (command), if user clicks on book button, then bookview should be shown or if user clicks on student button, then student view should be shown. I cannot get the correct and concise example for this issue. I would really appreciate if someone put a simple example. Thanks in advance.

```
 <Grid x:Name="MainMenu" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}">Menu</Label>
        <StackPanel Margin="10, 50,10,50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">Issue Book</Button>
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">Return Book</Button>
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">Add new Book</Button>
            <Button  Command="{Binding CreateCSV}"  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">View Book Data</Button>
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">Add new Student</Button>
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">View Student Data</Button>
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">View Issued Books</Button>
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">View Return Books</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which MVVM framework is the best framework for WPF apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069783/which-mvvm-framework-is-the-best-framework-for-wpf-apps)

Comment: you need to give some information before I answer.  Is Book View or student view usercontrols or window?

Comment: Bookview and student view are usercontrols.

Comment: Framework or no framework, two things must happen: Somewhere each button must be associated with the type/instance of usercontrol, and somewhere a new instance must be created. This either has to happen in code or in xaml. There are many ways to do this, but in order to give advice, it would be benificial to know exactly what you mean by no code-behind (does that include viewmodel), and why that is so important.